# Default type input and output signals SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to learn by myself SystemVerilog (I'm a university student and in my projects I've always used VHDL) and I have a question concerning data types. So far, I think I understood the differences, pro and cons between `reg`, `wire` and `logic` but I'm wondering, in this code snippet:

```
module example(

input clk,
input nrst,
input nset,
input up,
input [3:0] preload,
output [3:0] counter

);
```

what's the default type assigned to inputs and outputs? Is it logic (as it is the best choice for "everyday" circuitry)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SystemVerilog, `wire` and `reg/logic` are closely related, but independent concepts. `logic` is a *datatype*, and `wire` denotes a net (or network) signal *kind*. There are two basic signal kinds: nets(wire)  and variables(var) In a port list declaration, the default is `wire logic`, meaning a 1-bit 4-state net.

The defaults start to get more involved when you specify a *datatype* without a *kind* and the other way around. For inputs, the default unspecified *kind* is always a net, but for outputs, as soon as you specify a *datatype*, the default kind becomes `var`. Verilog appeals to lazy engineers who do not like coding. I suggest being explicit and never reyling on defaults.

I have some examples of this posted [here](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/usage-var#reply-42240).